# Omnet++ compound module: connect 1 input gate to multiple submodules

Tags: omnet++

I have made a simple compound module with 1 input and two submodules:

```
module System
{
    parameters:
    gates:
        input sensorDataIn;
    submodules:
        metric1: Metric1 {
            @display("p=30,26");
        }
        metric2: Metric2 {
            @display("p=30,26");
        }

    connections:
        sensorDataIn --> metric1.metricIn;
        sensorDataIn --> metric2.metricIn;
}
```

When I start the simulation I get an error that the gate is already connected. So how can I get the data that comes into my compound module to both submodules?

Thanks and kind regards,

tanktoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the hint of [Jerzy D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4653172/jerzy-d) I came to the following solution:

A simple module to distribute the messages:

```
simple Distributor
{ 
    parameters:
        int numOutputs = default(1);  
    gates:
        input dataIn @labels(SensorData/up);
        output dataOut[numOutputs];
}
```

In its implementation its forwarding the messages to all connected metrics:

```
void Distributor::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    // TODO - Generated method body
    for (int i=0; i<gateSize("dataOut"); i++) {
        cMessage *copy = msg->dup();
        send(copy, "dataOut", i);
    }
    delete msg;
}
```

And finally changed my System to:
module System
{
parameters:
gates:
input sensorDataIn;

```
submodules:
    distributor: Distributor{
        parameters:
            numOutputs = 2;
    }
    metric1: Metric1 {
        @display("p=30,26");
    }
    metric2: Metric2 {
        @display("p=30,26");
    }

connections:
    sensorDataIn --> distributor.dataIn;
    distributor.dataOut[0] --> metric1.metricIn;
    distributor.dataOut[1] --> metric2.metricIn;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

First, define `sensorDataIn` as a vector of gates by changing into:

```
gates:
  input sensorDataIn[2];
```

Second, use `++` operator for gate, i.e.:

```
connections:
  sensorDataIn++ --> metric1.metricIn;
  sensorDataIn++ --> metric2.metricIn;
```

Third, in your NED file for network change into:

```
 connections allowunconnected:
```

The size of vector of gates my be omitted because operator `++` automatically extends size of the vector of gates.

Comment: Thanks for this but now simulation crashed with "sensorDataIn[] gates are all connected, no gate left for '++' operator"

Comment: I have edited my answer by defining the size of the `sensorDataIn` as well as by adding annotations `allowunconnected` to your main NED file. However, I am not sure what exactly is your goal. Should module `System` have *one input* and the message received on this input should be forwarded to `metric1` and `metric2`? If yes, it cannot be achieved this way. A message cannot be copied and sent to many input  using connections only. It may be done using one input in `System` and additional simple module that will copy the message and send one copy to `metric1` and the second one to `metric2`.

Comment: "Should module System have one input and the message received on this input should be forwarded to metric1 and metric2?" This is exactly what I want to achieve. I first started with just one metric and everything was working fine up to the moment I added the second one.
So solution would be to add a new component in the compound model that has output[nrOfMetrics] and connect them to the metrics? And internally this module has to make copies and send them if I understood correctly.